# Dual-booted 2016 MacBook Pro suddenly shows seemingly random color for 30 seconds before crashing

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, display, crash, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Late 2016 15in MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. I tried running the installer a few times, but it would have this strange issue where the screen would turn a random color, seemingly based on the colors shown on screen.

Before installing Ubuntu, I tried installing Pop!_OS, which is Ubuntu based. The Pop!_OS installer had the same issue. However, the colors that appeared were different, since the colors of the installer were different. The first Pop!_OS crash, the entire screen went grey. Next was light blue, followed by white. I eventually tried Ubuntu, which had the same problem. First was orange, then black, then light grey.

However, by installing via “Install Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)” fixed the issue. After installing, however, the same problem occurs. It happens anywhere from 15 seconds after booting to 15 minutes. I can’t figure out what is causing it. I tried changing the display settings to see if anything changed, which it didn’t. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

If it isn’t already clear, I have very little experience with this, so don’t hesitate to ask for more information.

Edit: In case it’s useful, my built in graphics is Intel HD Graphics 530, with dedicated graphics being Radeon Pro 460.

I’m running Ubuntu Desktop 19.10 and I’m not using virtualization

I also established that when the screen goes blank and just shows a solid color, SSH still responds until the computer fully crashes a few seconds later.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: I have same issue. I successfully installed after a few tries. If I don't touch anything once the desktop loads it doesn't crash. But then when I try to do certain things it crashes to a grey or pink or orange screen. When I clicked on "Settings" it crashed and when I tried to get the wifi to work it crashed. Never the same exact action, but it is always some action that crashes it. Thinking maybe its GPU driver related.